# populating a listview within a datatemplate

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, datatemplate

I am currently having problems accessing the listview within a DataTemplate, each row has its unique list, for example Sam has certain documents that needs click events, I just cant access the name of the control.

Through research I have discovered command and using the visual tree helper, however cant access the list to bind data with the itemsource.

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgUsers">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Binding="{Binding name1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Land Line" Binding="{Binding landline}"/>         
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate">
                <DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ListView x:Name="lvPipeline" Margin="10,82,10,156" Grid.Column="2" >
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xaml you can access named controls in a template like yours only in the template and not from the outside.
Not sure if i understand the general application context all the way but I would use MVVM and create a model and viewmodel for objects like Sam and put Sam's documentlist in the viewmodel and bind it to the listbox in the datatemplate.

My approach would be something like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set}
    public ObservableCollection<string> Documents {get;set;}
    public string SelectedDocument {get;set}

}



  <DataGrid Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
              <!--  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Land Line" Binding="{Binding LandLine}"/>    -->     
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate">
                    <DockPanel Background="GhostWhite">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDocument}" Margin="10,82,10,156" Grid.Column="2" >
                                 <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView>
```

After that you can use the SelectedDocument property and bind it to a e.g. document viewer.

Comment: thanks for the reply, How will the binding to the documents be unique to each user?

Comment: thanks for the reply, How will the binding to the documents be unique to each user?

Comment: You have to bind the docs to a User. You could also create a doc class to get unique id for each doc (from database)